# Specify the path to node when running executable npm moduels

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm, npm-install

I'm fairly new to node and npm so imagine this might be the way I'm trying to use it. My understanding so far and questions are as follows.

When installing modules with npm if they have executables they are created in `node_moadules/.bin`

For example `npm install istanbul` creates 
`node_moadules/.bin/istanbul.cmd` with the following contents

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\istanbul\lib\cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\istanbul\lib\cli.js" %*
)
```

This seems to be roughly similar for other npm modules installed.

**1)** When would there be a node.exe in the bin directory (`%~dp0` is the path of the batch file - so `node_moadules/.bin`)? When using `npm istanbul` it will use the above script but I don't understand when it would use the IF block, it seems it would always go into the ELSE which uses node on the path to run it. This will work as intended when I have node installed and on my path. However this would seem to be a problem if you don't have it on your path or need to use a specific version in a project (different from the version on your path).

**2)** I can fix this by manually editing the above script to point to the specific node version but don't want to have to do this for all module executables installed with npm. Is there a way to configure this in npm so it uses a specific path to node when it generates these executable files?

**A bit more background**

We're using the [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md) in our build so we don't have to manage node and npm on our build machines, this does it for us. However this means we don't have node on the path.

The plugin allows me to install npm modules but there is no clear way to then run the executables, using the version of node unpacked by the plugin, without manually editing the generated executable scripts as in **2)**, or instead of calling `npm istanbul` calling something like this:
`<path_to>\node <path_to>\node_modules\istanbul\lib\cli.js`

This also doesn't seem right as I'm hardcoding to the `cli.js` executable path within the module which could presumably change in future versions of that module.

If anyone could explain this, or tell me where the specific part of the docs that do are that would be helpful. I've tried to search but probably not using the right terms.